# How to remove Version Information from Encrypted OpenPGP message in Windows?

Tags: windows, gnupg, pgp

I am using Keybase.io with GnuPG on Windows 8.1 via Powershell. I am wondering how to remove the Version line from the encrypted and or signed message.  Here is example if what I mean:

```
-----BEGIN PGP MESSAGE----- 
Version: GnuPG v2  <-- **Remove this (line).**

owEBTQGy/pANAwACARsm2bqGdVliAcsdYgBUavgLVGVzdCBmb3IgU3RhY2tPdmVy
ZmxvdyCJARwEAAECAAYFAlRq+AsACgkQGybZuoZ1WWKlVgf/cfsU/aJYnNIimAwq
DKKfWox9c7rEC5ug6qcQzb5YFPsGuyMtZ1Tx9SwCmvU7IXtlnK/BY6H4ut50zOzl
8O8fYaaK63NupeEThlNK1fMvTmt56GLRSgGZ9yBOdkaC3A3SWBAsniPoj5wjBr7m
/MHnqs5Gw1Mtp8I8issZzTQXGjq4j6mAli1Vb3lBpESuF/s/uOxY8jSCV8SDH0UU
RxKoVnzqXd7mD2Dv+KE8K1PKVbVNyT+vIc+rOsRKkaW+6rSXVXie4DWkKxCP5RPe
3Ma3KMark71EwNW86IWryFm8YkP4vt31HKMwW4HUb6nhFF24IQOPle51YoiyZWUC
ejtY4Q==
=xKTQ

-----END PGP MESSAGE-----
```

Also, I have found the option that you can add into the options, but I cannot find the options file itself (`gpg.conf`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft Windows, the configuration files are stored under [`%APPDATA%\gnupg`](http://www.gpg4win.org/doc/en/gpg4win-compendium_28.html). For recent versions of Microsoft Windows, this directory will by default be stored in

```
C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\gnupg
```

The comment string can be changed by editing the `comment` option, or the option removed completely. To remove the version, add a line containing the option `no-emit-version` which does not require a value. From `man gpg` (all non-abbreviated command line options can be used without the `--` prefix in `gpg.conf`):

```
--comment string
--no-comments
     Use  string  as  a comment string in clear text signatures and ASCII
     armored messages or keys (see --armor). The default behavior is not to
     use a comment string. --comment may be repeated multiple times to get
     multiple comment strings. --no-comments removes all comments.  It is a
     good idea to keep the length of  a  single  comment  below  60 characters
     to avoid problems with mail programs wrapping such lines.  Note that
     comment lines, like all other header lines, are not protected by the
     signature.

--emit-version
--no-emit-version
     Force inclusion of the version string in ASCII armored output.  If given
     once only the name of the program and the major number is emitted
     (default), given twice the minor is also emitted, given triple the micro
     is added, and given quad an operating system identification is also emitted.
     --no-emit-version disables the version line.
```

Comment: Thank you and to remove the version do I just add this `no-emit-version` after the keyserver line, on line 4?

Comment: Overlooked you're not after a comment, but the version information. Yes, you're right, I edited my answer. Where you add the line does not matter.